# How to make the Settings Activity return to the correct fragment in the Main Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a simple android app based on the Basic Activity. I have 6 fragments that are displayed in the Main Activity depending on the state of a finite state machine (https://github.com/Tinder/StateMachine).

The state machine changes state based on input from the different fragments, and also on background processes. For example, if the app looses contact with a bluetooth connected device, then the state changes, and so does the fragment displayed in the Main Activity. I have a Settings Activity with a few options, as well.

So far, all the code works. When the state changes, whether via background processes or button clicks on the currently displayed fragment, the screen changes correctly.

My question relates to the toolbar back button in the Settings Activity. The back button returns to the correct Main Activity fragment, except if the state changes while the I am viewing the Settings Activity. I am not sure how to get the Settings Activity toolbar back button to go to the correct fragment in the Main Activity when a background process change the current state.

I launch the Settings Activity in the Main Activity using:

```
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> {
                // launch settings activity
                startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, SettingsActivity::class.java))
                return true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

In the Settings Activity I have:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            LOG.info("trying to get home")
            finish()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

I have this code in the Main Activity to change the fragment based on the new state of the state machine:

```
   fun renderViewState(newTransition: RLSideEffect, message: String) {
        LOG.info("MainActivity: renderView: newTransition=$newTransition")
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        when (newTransition) {
            is RLSideEffect.LogStart -> {
                LOG.info("MainActivity: LogStart")
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_StartFragment)
                toast { message }
            }
            is RLSideEffect.LogConnected -> {
                LOG.info("MainActivity: Connected")
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_ConnectedFragment)
                toast { message }
            }
            is RLSideEffect.LogContinuityOK -> {
                LOG.info("MainActivity LogContinuityOK")
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_ContinuityOkFragment)
                toast { message }
            }
            is RLSideEffect.LogContinuityFailed -> {
                LOG.info("MainActivity: LogContinuityFailed")
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_ContinuityFailedFragment)
                toast { message }
            }
            is RLSideEffect.LogArmed -> {
                LOG.info("MainActivity: LogArmed")
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_ArmedFragment)
                toast { message }
            }
            is RLSideEffect.LogIgnition -> {
                LOG.info("MainActivity: LogIgnition")
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_IgnitionFragment)
                toast { message }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I get the Settings Activity to return to the current state (fragment) of the Main Activity, and not just the point the Settings Activity was launched from?

Comment: You could use the start activity for result mechanism. But wouldn’t it be simpler to have a settings fragment hosted by the same activity?

Comment: Most definitely! Can you point me to a resource that would help me change the way I am launching the Settings Fragment?

Comment: Like any other fragment in the navgraph. And it can call this Activity function you showed.

Comment: Actually, Your idea won't work in my application. If I launch the Settings Fragment from the Main Activity it will show the Settings Fragment, but if, for example, the Bluetooth signal is lost, the Main Activity will take the user out of the Settings Fragment and drop him/her into a different fragment because the state machine will change state. The Settings Fragment has to be in its own Activity so the state machine can change state if needed, and the Settings Fragment stays on the screen. So, how do I make the Settings Activity come back to the correct fragment in the Main Activity?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: Thanks for the link. After reading through it, I am not sure it applies.  It seems to cover Activity_A -> Activity_B, and Activity_B returns a result to Activity_A. I have the situation of Activity_A -> Activity_B, and the state of Activity_A changing before Activity_B returns, so Activity_B returns to the wrong fragment in Activity_A. I am not sure how, in Activity_B to return to the correct fragment in Activity_A.

Comment: So change your existing logic to handle the case of reacting to returned information from the second activity.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion on using the  `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` APIs. After some more reading, it made sense and solved my problem without too many changes to the existing code.